# Why does Slick not provide a TRUNCATE method on ddl?

Tags: sql, scala, slick, truncate

I'm currently falling back to sql"truncate X".execute

TRUNCATE is Standard SQL according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_%28SQL%29

Can't figure out why there is no mention of it either on the docs nor on the whole Internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because nobody implemented it yet. I just did that: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1029 . We'll try to get it into 2.2 end of January. I am optimistic.